# Redirection doesn't work from ARR but works within DNN

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, arr

We have an IIS web farm, of which consisting an load balancer, 4 ARRs, and 2 ASP.NET application servers running DNN CMS. The 4 ARRs will URL rewrite to DNN application servers. We have more than 100 URLs that need to be redirected into more specific resources within the website.

For example, when a user types in `http://www.abcd.com/product1` from outside, the desired outcome is to redirect to `www.abcd.com/index.aspx?articleid=1234` , we have configured such behavior within DNN environment, and we can sure that it works, as when we browse the site within the DNN application server, the DNN is able to detect the URL and perform redirection accordingly.

Problem occurs when we attempt to browse the `http://www.abcd.com/product1` from LB and ARRs, when we type `http://www.abcd.com/product1`, it simply go back to `http://www.abcd.com` mainpage, which the redirection doesn't work at all. No IIS level HTTP redirection has been performed at the ARRs and LBs, the only setting is the default URL rewrite rule which will rewrite the URL to backend DNN servers.

Same question has been posted in IIS forum as well, it is just that I decided to post it here again to gain more exposure.

Comment: Good question! Are you in a position to debug with Visual Studio? I had rewrite issues of my own and resolved them by stepping through the  DNN source as it was executing. You can confirm exactly what inputs DNN is receiving, and what outputs it is sending to the DNN core for processing

Comment: The DNN settings were all configured by developers side, I have no access over it, I can confirm it is working by loading the link on the DNN application server browser.

Answer (score 1):

When going through the ARR are you calling off to the specific IP?  For example does `http://www.abcd.com/product1` become `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/product1` by chance?

If so, you might want to add those as additional portal aliases to the DNN site.

Otherwise, you will might want to use something like Fiddler to see exactly what is going on with redirects/responses.

Comment: I put in the exact same URL which is http://www.abcd.com/ in the URL rewrite field, but I have hacked the host file of the ARRs, so that anything with www.abcd.com will point to the private IP of the DNN server.